# Will Ubuntu work on my new build?

Tags: compatibility

I am getting a new desktop soon and wanted to know if Ubuntu is compatible with my build. I will be using it to play Minecraft on high settings with shaders enabled. Here is the complete list of hardware.

CPU- AMD FX 6300 3.5Ghz 6-Core

Mobo- Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3P ATX AM3+ Motherboard

GPU- Sapphire Radeon R9 270X 2GB Vapor-X Video Card

RAM- G.Skill Ripjaws X Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR3-1866 Memory

Storage- Sandisk SSD PLUS 120GB 2.5" Solid State Drive

Power Supply- Rosewill 750W 80+ Bronze Certified ATX Power Supply

Case- Cooler Master Elite 431 Plus (Black) ATX Mid Tower Case

Mouse- UtechSmart Venus 50 to 16400 DPI High Precision Laser MMO Gaming Mouse for PC

I will be displaying it on my 32" Samsung 1080p HDTV. I had Ubuntu on an old Core 2 Duo HP desktop and loved it, if this build is compatible with Ubuntu then I don't need to worry about getting another copy of windows for my new build.

If you need more info, please let me know!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware compatibility questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you should be fine. NVIDIA graphics have problems on Ubuntu, so it's good you use AMD graphics. I actually have a similar rig (same RAM, graphics and CPU) and Ubuntu runs just fine. Just as a sort of caveat, Ubuntu tends to cap game FPS at your monitor's refresh rate (VSync), which isn't necessarily bad, just something you should know. A quick Google search didn't show any errors, but I did skim. I think you're good, and of it doesn't work, it's easy to uninstall Ubuntu and put something like Fedora or Windows on.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your insight. I went for AMD because it really seems the best alternative to Intel for the price point. I might add a dedicated monitor in the future but right now I just want to keep the price down as much as possible. How did you search on google? I tried searching for specific hardware compatibility with Ubuntu and only received mixed results with builds completely different than mine other than that specific part.

Comment: I just searched `gigabyte motherboard Ubuntu`.